# google recaptcha are not working?

Tags: codeigniter, recaptcha

controller: test.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Test extends CI_Controller 
{
    function __construct() 
    {
        parent :: __construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->model('Fetch_data'); 
    }

    public function login()
    {
        $this->load->view('login');
    }

    public function signin()
    { 
        $firstName = trim($this->input->post('fname')); 
        $email = trim($this->input->post('email')); 
        $phone = trim($this->input->post('mobile')); 
        $recaptchaResponse = trim($this->input->post('g-recaptcha-response')); 
        $userIp=$this->input->ip_address(); 
        $secret='******************************'; 
        $url="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secret."&response;=".$recaptchaResponse."&remoteip;=".$userIp; 
        $response = $this->curl->simple_get($url); 
        $status= json_decode($response, true); 
        if($status['success'])
        { 
            $this->session->set_flashdata('flashSuccess', 'Google Recaptcha Successful'); 
        }
        else
        { 
            $this->session->set_flashdata('flashSuccess', 'Sorry Google Recaptcha Unsuccessful!!'); 
        } 
        redirect(base_url('index.php/test/login')); 
    }
}
```

view: login.php

```
<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('message');?>
<div class="error"><strong><?=$this->session->flashdata('flashSuccess')?></strong></div>
<hr/>
<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="Your First Name" class="text-line"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" class="text-line"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" placeholder="Your Mobile" class="text-line"/>
    </div>
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="*********************************"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" name="signup" id="signup" value="Sign Up" class="btn btn-warning"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

In this code, I am using google recaptcha. when I have checked recaptcha checkbox
then it could not show message i.e. Google Recaptcha Successful or Sorry Google Recaptcha Unsuccessful. I don't know why ? can any body tell me where I am doing wrong ?

Comment: anyone help me plss

Comment: can anybody help me plss

Comment: google captcha used

Comment: what wrong with this @HothiJimit

Comment: when you wrong captcha and form submit  that time new session used for new captcha

Comment: ya but I want this right now.

Comment: https://www.formget.com/codeigniter-captcha-helper/  check for refrence

Comment: I am using google recaptcha @HothiJimit but on check checkbox it could not showing successfull message. why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148055/discussion-between-omkara-and-hothi-jimit).